# How to set value of element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium

I want to fill element from application with numbers.

From appium i know i want to fill:

```
element: aaa/edit_input_activation_code_first

attribute: text

value: 5 numbers eg.: 12345
```

I use below code for move between screens.

```
it("should find an element", function() {
  return driver
    .elementById('aaa/btn_registration_wizard_fragment_type_code')
    .should.eventually.exist
});


it("should find click element", function() {
  return driver
    .elementById('aaa/btn_registration_wizard_fragment_type_code')
    .click()
});
```

I want to fill 4 elements with numbers and then move on to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send some keys to a text element, you should use that method:

```
let element = await driver.elementById("aaa/edit_input_activation_code_first");
await element.type("12345")
```